# How to insert Training and Testing data into Tensorflow's high API WITHOUT manually splitting the CSV myself

Tags: tensorflow, split, scikit-learn

Everyone, I found it super inefficient to literally create and prepare two CSV's - training and testing data - to then feed them separately into Tensorflow's high API (tf.estimator).

Is there a way to make this process more efficient? I want to do something like sklearn's model_selection module where the module takes in one large CSV, splits the data into testing and training, and then feeds it into the estimator for predictions and evaluations. But I don't think Tensorflow's high API takes in data split by sklearn's model_selection.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: I think Simon hit the answer on the head, and should post that as an answer. The concern I have with not splitting your dataset at the file level is that it's really easy to accidentally feed your test data in as training data. If you make a tweak to your indexing code (finiky stuff, indexing) you can drastically skew your results and think you're doing great when you're doing crap. It's really embarrassing to make this mistake, you tell everyone it works great, only to have it bomb on you when integrated into a live system. Tread carefully.

Comment: Hi thank you both, but I know the model_selection module. The problem is that the Tensorflow high API (tf.estimator) doesn't accept data that's been processed and split by the model_selection module. Or at least I don't think it does. I literally have to create two different CSV's (training and testing data) and feed it to the tf.estimator separately. That's the way tf.estimator seems to be designed. This is why I'm saying it's super inefficient. Please let me know if I missed anything. https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/estimators